# UIScrollView not allow to move down when drag

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, pull-to-refresh

I want to my scrollView not move down when I drag the scrollView down, in other word,I don't want the contentOffset be changed when I pull to refresh the scrollVIew content,how can I do that?

Comment: set Content size of scrollview  same as scrollview height

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want to `bounce` ScrollView... Just unselect Attribute Named `Bounce` as like below from `Show the Attributes Inspector`

[image]

or You can do that `Programmatically` like this

ScrollObj.bounces = NO;